# In Java, in terms of performance, is a <= comparison the same as a less than comparison followed by an OR followed by an equal to comparison?

Tags: java, performance

Is the code

```
 while(currentLine <= endLine)  
  {
     // more code
     currentLine++;  
  }
```

equivalent to

```
 while(currentLine < endLine || currentLine == endLine)
  {
     // more code
     currentLine++;   
  }
```

in terms of performance?

Comment: I think both are same. JVM inlines wherever possible and it is better don't overengineer.

Comment: At least as important: the first version is more readable and has less potential for typos.

Comment: (a) this depends on how this is compiled to java byte code and how the jvm then converts the byte code to native code, (b) at that level it may be system dependent (c) this issue is a non-issue - this will never never never be your bottleneck.

Comment: If the second one was faster, then the Java compiler would trivially be able to emit code corresponding to the second case whenever the programmer wrote `<=`...

Comment: If the comparison was not against a variable, but instead a function, say endLine(), then the compile would have to analyze sidefects as results could be very different.

Comment: @thinksteep They are not the same, and it is trivially easy to show it via javap. The first one compiles to a single comparison; the second one, to two comparisons and a jump.

Comment: @EJP, compile time I don't know what byte will be generated. I am talking about runtime. AFAIK, most of modern JVMs inline possible statements and I feel this would be one case for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `<=` operation typically compiles down into a single bytecode instruction `if_icmple` or `ifle`.  How the JVM interprets that is typically machine-dependent, but most hardware has support to evaluate < and <= as a single instruction.  Consequently, you should probably expect the performance for `<=` to be the same as `<`.

The Java compiler can potentially rewrite the second code as the first, meaning that there will be no performance penalty.  However, this is an implementation detail.

Generally speaking, don't worry about these sorts of microoptimizations unless you are sure that they're the reason for a performance bottleneck.  It's extremely rare that decisions like this will have a profound effect on program runtime.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I deleted my answer, I don't remember what I saw. I got you now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could argue if the short circuit logic is more efficient than the comparison, I would go for the first, anyway If the optimizer is smart enough it wouldn't matter how you write it.

Comment: Wait no you can't argue that. A comparison is a single operation on *every* CPU ISA I know and usually implemented as a simple sub (and there's usually nothing more efficient than a simple add/sub for obvious reasons). The shortcircuit operation itself is implemented as a comparison followed by a jump - in no way more efficient.